# Read CSV with new line character inside cells

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to read two columns from csv, rows are separeted by ';'.

I am using `stram.ReadLine` method, but the problem is that some cells have text which has new line character, and because of that, method `ReadLine` breaks that cell into few others, how can I avoid this ? To simplify this model lets say i have one column with 100 rows, but some of them have long text inside and some break lines, how can I modify this to have 100 rows and not more?

```
StreamReader aFile = new StreamReader("C:\\dev\\csvReplacment\\szablonDE.csv");


            var dane = new List<string>();

            string line;

            while ((line = aFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                dane.Add(line);
            }
            aFile.Close();
```

Comment: have you tried walgreens instead

Comment: walgreens ? whats that ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents? Also, if there are new lines, chances are you don't want to `ReadLine`, but instead read until the next occurrence of a `;` or the end of the file (whichever comes first).

Comment: i think in your title you mean CSV is all.  Can you post a sample CSV

Comment: how can I read content of csv with \r and \n ?

Comment: You can't read the CSV line by line if a raw can spand multiple lines. I'd encode the new line chars when exporting the CSV to have an entry on a single line; don't know if you can do that though.

Comment: I just implemented a CSV reader in C#. My code reads each "line" field-by-field, and each field is read character-by-character, keeping track of quoting. You will have to do something similar if you want to be able to read fields containing newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `;` marks the end of a line:

```
    // Build your final resulting list
    List<String> dane = new List<String>();

    // use StreamReader to read the file
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        // create a string builder that we can use to store each
        // line's contents until it's ready to be added to dane
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // buffer char
        Char c;
        // read the stream character by character
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            c = (Char)sr.Read();
            // if it's `;` it's the end of a row, so add it to
            // dane and reset the line's contents
            if (c == ';')
            {
                dane.Add(builder.ToString());
                builder.Clear();
            }
            // avoid reading in superfluous whitespace before we
            // begin reading a line
            else if (builder.Length == 0 && Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                continue;
            }
            // concatenate the current character to our line
            else
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }
        }
        // if there's a final row, add it to dane
        if (builder.Length > 0)
        {
            dane.Add(builder.ToString());
        }
    }

    // dane now contains each line's contents.
```

You could probably optimize this and read in 1024 characters at a time and search for the `;` within, but this is just a primitive example to show you how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing CSV parser from Nuget. 
"CSVTools" on Nuget (http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvTools/ ) handles this and is pretty fast an supports binding to strong .NET types for easy parsing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/03/24/opensource-csv-reader-on-nuget.aspx

Usage is like this:

```
var dt = DataAccess.DataTable.New.Read(@"c:\temp\test.csv"); 
foreach (Row row in dt.Rows())  { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you simply use some existing code/lib instead of going to this huddle your self

http://csvfile.codeplex.com/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12170/FileHelpers-v2-0-Delimited-CSV-or-Fixed-Data-Impor

Are just 2 out there

I would also recommend using the ServiceStack.Text nuget
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text/3.9.64