# How to import a CSV which can have a line break in some rows for a certain column?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, text-files, multiline

I have a CSV with records which have break line but I have consider it in same row.

Here is a sample:

```html
• strbarcode,strdescription,strsize,decprice,intcaseqty,deccost,vat,departmentId
• 5015397310361,Yellow/Black Post Complete with Base ,1,0.01,2,0.01,20,18
• 5015397615305,"Hand sanitiser board c/w manual dispenser - 6 image design - Turquoise (300 x 400mm)
• Complete with fixings",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
• ,"Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - Hands - Blue (300 x 400mm)
• Complete with fixings",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
• ,"Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - Hands - Turquiose (300 x 400mm)
• Complete with fixings",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
• ,"Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - 3 image design - Blue (300 x 400mm)
• Complete with fixings",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
• 5015397310354,Red/White Post Complete with Base ,1,0.01,2,0.01,20,18
```

Here is my current code:

```
private void ImportProductDataFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        pictureBox_loading.Visible = true;
        pictureBox_loading.Refresh();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header);
            dtnew.Columns.Add(header);
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = Regex.Split(sr.ReadLine(), ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rows.Length > 0 && i >= (rows.Length))
                {
                    dr[i] = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        var emptyRows = dt.Select().Where(
               row => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().All(column => string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[column].ToString()))).ToArray();
        Array.ForEach(emptyRows, x => x.Delete());
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        if (dt.Columns.Contains("departmentId"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Remove("departmentId");
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        if (dtnew.Columns.Contains("departmentId"))
        {
            dtnew.Columns.Remove("departmentId");
            dtnew.AcceptChanges();
        }
        //dt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new { strbarcode = r.Field<string>("strbarcode")}).Select(g => g.Last()).CopyToDataTable();
        dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("strbarcode").Trim(),
             (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(
                 y =>
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         return Convert.ToDecimal(y.Field<string>("decprice"));
                     }
                     catch (Exception)
                     {
                         return Decimal.Zero;
                     }
                 }
             ).First()).CopyToDataTable();
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        //add data dt to dtnew 
        DataRow Rownew;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)//dt  as sourcetable and dt new as destination  table
        {
            Rownew = dtnew.NewRow();
            //if (row["strbarcode"].ToString().Trim() == "")
            //{
            //    continue;
            //}
            Rownew["strbarcode"] = row["strbarcode"].ToString().Trim() != "" ? row["strbarcode"].ToString() : "";
            Rownew["strdescription"] = row["strdescription"].ToString().Trim() != "" ? row["strdescription"].ToString().Replace(",", "") : "";
            Rownew["strsize"] = row["strsize"].ToString() != "" ? row["strsize"].ToString() : "";
            Rownew["decprice"] = row["decprice"].ToString().Trim() != "" ? objUtility.ToDecimal(row["decprice"].ToString()) : 0;
            Rownew["intcaseqty"] = row["intcaseqty"].ToString().Trim() != "" ? objUtility.ToInt(row["intcaseqty"].ToString()) : 0;
            Rownew["deccost"] = row["deccost"].ToString().Trim() != "" ? objUtility.ToDecimal(row["deccost"].ToString()) : 0;
            Rownew["vat"] = row["vat"].ToString().Trim() != "" ? objUtility.ToDecimal(row["vat"].ToString()) : 0;
            dtnew.Rows.Add(Rownew);
        }
        dtnew.AcceptChanges();
        sr.Close();
        //create use type table and stored procedure 
        string strStatus = OjbDataAccess.UpdateDBForImportProductSP();
        if (strStatus == "success")
        {
            //inserting and updating data in plof database 
            string strMsg = OjbDataAccess.ImportProdcttosuperplofInsertUpdate(dtnew);
            pictureBox_loading.Visible = false;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            MessageBox.Show(strMsg, "Data Import Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox_loading.Visible = false;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            MessageBox.Show(strStatus, "Data Import Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        pictureBox_loading.Visible = false;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        txtFile.Text = string.Empty;
        btnImportFile.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid CSV file");
        WriteErrorLog("=============================================================================" + Environment.NewLine);
        WriteErrorLog("Product CSV file is not imported  due to some error in import file." + Environment.NewLine);
        WriteErrorLog(ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        WriteErrorLog("=============================================================================" + Environment.NewLine);
        return;
    }
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a standards-compliant CSV library that knows how to deal with quoting instead of rolling your own?

Comment: Instead of inventing the wheel unless you want to make one, take a look at [FileHelpers](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers) • [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) • [FlatFiles](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/FlatFiles) • [NugetMustHaves:CSV](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package?q=csv)

Comment: If you absolutely want to implement your own CSV reader, I suggest using tokens instead of Regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line breaks in generated csv file driving me crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952027/line-breaks-in-generated-csv-file-driving-me-crazy) and [Read CSV with new line character inside cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183102/read-csv-with-new-line-character-inside-cells) and [Read CSV that contained newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193822/read-csv-that-contained-newline)

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your text file is always the same, a single regular expression can parse the file:

```cs
    Regex lineExp = new Regex(@"(?<strbarcode>[0-9]+)?,((?<strdescription>[^,""]+)|""(?<strdescription>[^""]+)""),(?<strsize>[0-9]+),(?<decprice>[0-9.]+),(?<intcaseqty>[0-9]+),(?<deccost>[0-9.]+),(?<vat>[0-9]+),(?<departmentId>[0-9]+)([\r\n]+|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex lineBreakExp = new Regex(@"[\r\n+]", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    string data = @"strbarcode,strdescription,strsize,decprice,intcaseqty,deccost,vat,departmentId
5015397310361,Yellow/Black Post Complete with Base ,1,0.01,2,0.01,20,18
5015397615305,""Hand sanitiser board c/w manual dispenser - 6 image design - Turquoise (300 x 400mm)
Complete with fixings"",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
,""Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - Hands - Blue (300 x 400mm)
Complete with fixings"",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
,""Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - Hands - Turquiose (300 x 400mm)
Complete with fixings"",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
,""Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - 3 image design - Blue (300 x 400mm)
Complete with fixings"",1,0.01,0,0.01,20,18
5015397310354,Red/White Post Complete with Base ,1,0.01,2,0.01,20,18
5015397310361,""YProduct with delimiter, so take care"",1,0.01,2,0.01,20,18
5015397310361,Product with incalid strsize will be ignored,a,0.01,2,0.01,20,18
5015397310361,Last line ends not with CRLF,3,0.01,2,0.01,20,18";

    var matches = lineExp.Matches(data);
    int i = 1;
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        Console.Write($"Item {i++}\t");
        Console.Write($"{m.Groups["strbarcode"].Value}\t");
        Console.Write($"{lineBreakExp.Replace(m.Groups["strdescription"].Value, " ")}\t");
        Console.Write($"{m.Groups["strsize"].Value}\t");
        Console.Write($"{m.Groups["decprice"].Value}\t");
        Console.Write($"{m.Groups["intcaseqty"].Value}\t");
        Console.Write($"{m.Groups["deccost"].Value}\t");
        Console.Write($"{m.Groups["vat"].Value}\t");
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["departmentId"].Value);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Item 1  5015397310361   Yellow/Black Post Complete with Base    1   0.01    2   0.01    20  18
Item 2  5015397615305   Hand sanitiser board c/w manual dispenser - 6 image design - Turquoise (300 x 400mm)  Complete with fixings 1   0.01    0   0.01    20  18
Item 3      Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - Hands - Blue (300 x 400mm)  Complete with fixings   1   0.01    0   0.01    20  18
Item 4      Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - Hands - Turquiose (300 x 400mm)  Complete with fixings  1   0.01    0   0.01    20  18
Item 5      Barrier cream board c/w with manual dispenser - 3 image design - Blue (300 x 400mm)  Complete with fixings  1   0.01    0   0.01    20  18
Item 6  5015397310354   Red/White Post Complete with Base   1   0.01    2   0.01    20  18
Item 7  5015397310361   YProduct with delimiter, so take care   1   0.01    2   0.01    20  18
Item 8  5015397310361   Last line ends not with CRLF    3   0.01    2   0.01    20  18
```

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a couple libraries that might help you: [Sylvan.Data.Csv](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sylvan.Data.Csv/) and [Sylvan.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sylvan.Data/). The Csv library provides `CsvDataReader` which handles parsing CSV data with quoted fields with delimiters and new lines such as in your file. The `Sylvan.Data` library (currently prerelease, but available on nuget) provides the `Schema` type which can be used to apply a strongly typed schema to your CSV data. Together, these libraries make it very easy to load a `DataTable` with strongly-typed data from a CSV file.

```
// define a schema for your csv.
var schema = Schema.Parse("strbarcode,strdescription,strsize,decprice:decimal,intcaseqty:int,deccost:decimal,vat:int,departmentId:int");
// provide the schema when constructing the CsvDataReader
var options = new CsvDataReaderOptions { Schema = new CsvSchema(schema) };
var data = CsvDataReader.Create("data.csv", options);
var dt = new DataTable();
// Load the data table with the csv data
dt.Load(data);
```

I don't have any documentation for the Schema.Parse syntax, but all of the .NET primitive types are supported. You can also remap column names via the schema if you desire using ">" notation:
`"strbarcode>BarCode,strdescription>Description,strsize>Size,decprice>Price:decimal,intcaseqty>CaseQuantity:int,deccost>Cost:decimal,vat>Vat:int,departmentId>DepartmentId:int"`

`Sylvan.Data.Csv` also happens to be the fastest CSV parser in the .NET ecosystem, so if you have huge files to deal with you won't find a faster solution.